# Websockets connection longs much time

Tags: websocket, raspberry-pi

I try the same code on my desktop and on Rasbperry Pi ([code on github](https://github.com/eddyem/rasp-spect)). And I found that on Raspberry Pi websocket connection opens very long time (sometimes it takes one or even two minutes till establishes).

In firebug's console I don't see any warnings and errors when connection established, so I can thing that websocket really opens such long time.

But when I try this on my desktop (both with "localhost" in WS address and with "127.0.0.1" in it) the connection established very fast!

What a bug can it be?

Comment: DNS and reverse name loopup?

Comment: @kometen, don't think so: ping works good. Raspberry is in local subnet, goes out through my desktop which works as gateway through DNAT. IP of Raspberry is in no_proxy list, browser also keep it in list of direct connection. HTML connections to Raspberry works pretty fine, but websockets connection lasts too long.